# Split a date column, and calculate an amount based on the result

Tags: sql-server

In the sales table I have a column that contains full dates of each sale, I need to split it and add 2 separate columns of month and year to the sales table, and a column that contains the sum of all sales of each month that was.

This is the table I have-

**Sales table**

| customer_id | date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | 6 |
| 124 | 01/02/2020 | 7 |
| 123 | 01/03/2021 | 5 |
| 123 | 15/01/2020 | 4 |

Here's what I wrote -

```
ALTER TABLE SALES ADD SELECT DATEPART (year, date) as year FROM SALES;

ALTER TABLE SALES ADD SELECT DATEPART (month, date) as month FROM SALES;

ALTER TABLE SALES ADD SUM_Quantity AS SUM() (Here I was stuck in a query...)
```

Is this a valid query, and how to write it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Create a view instead.

Comment: BTW, is this MS SQL Server or?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: THIS IS IN SQL SERVER

Comment: do you really need to change the table structure? or do you just need a query that returns the sum of sales by month / year ?

Comment: I need to change the table because later I need to do new calculations on the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems you're going to have here is that the outcome of the computed columns you have isn't compatible with the data being stored.
For example you can't build a sum of the quantity for all of the rows in January for each row in January. You need to group by the date and aggregate the quantity.

As such I think this might be an ideal candidate for an indexed view. This will allow you to store the calculated data, whilst preserving the data in the original table.

```
create table SalesTable (customer_id int, date date, quantity smallint);

insert SalesTable (customer_id, date, quantity)
select 123, '2020-01-01', 6
union
select 124, '2020-02-01', 7
union
select 123, '2021-03-01', 5
union
select 123, '2020-01-15', 4;

select * from SalesTable order by date; /*original data set*/

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vwSalesTable /*indexed view*/
   WITH SCHEMABINDING
   AS  
      SELECT customer_id, DATEPART(year, date) as year, datepart(MONTH, date) as 
month, SUM(quantity) as sum_quantity from dbo.SalesTable group by Customer_Id, 
DATEPART(year, date), DATEPART(MONTH, date)
  GO

  select * from vwSalesTable /*data from your indexed view*/

drop view vwSalesTable;
drop table SalesTable;
```

[image: Original data set on top and indexed view output below]

Comment: magnificent
I understood the idea thanks to you.
Thanks

Comment: Dwight Reynoldson, 
At the end of each run, what is the name of the final table? (Or alternatively where did you define the final table name)?

Comment: So the name can be whatever you like, usually for a view you place "vw" as a prefix. So in the sample sent over I simply called the indexed view vwSalesTable.